# Method for implementing multiple costumes to an animated 3D game character?

Tags: ios, animation, unity-game-engine, modeling

We'd like to include unlockable outfits in our mobile game, but how does one manage this? Right now, my modeler exports the animations within the character model's .FBX file. But now that we want to create some additional costumes, we don't know how to proceed.

How do popular games do this — For example: how does Tomb Raider handle all Lara Croft's additional outfits without re-doing the animations for each one?

Are all outfits treated as 'clothes' that are applied to a single nude, animated model and enabled/disabled accordingly? Or is there a full, individual character model for every outfit? (In which case, how would we associate the animations?)

Another thing I wonder about is how to handle texturing in all this?

Finally, should we take any additional considerations for this being a mobile game? (i.e., Should we [can we?] split things into separate files, or do we need to keep all outfits and all animation in a single, large file?